# Ruby Geocoder for google business

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, activerecord, google-maps-api-3

Im using the Geocoder gem for ruby.  With V2 of the google maps API for business you could pass in your API key in `config/initializers/geocoder.rb` in V3 of the API they no longer give you an API key but rather a `client-id` which is basically a cryptographic key that you use to create a signature for the url.  Since I cannot obtain an API Key I dont quite know how to do the latter.  Has anyone ran into this problem?  If so could you please point me in a direction other than googles documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following config should work(Replace with your own information):

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
Geocoder.configure do |config|
  config.lookup = :google_premier
  config.api_key = [ 'GOOGLE_CRYPTO_KEY', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CHANNEL' ]
  config.timeout = 10
  config.units = :km
end
```